# Prove that there exist exactly two motions which map two line segments of the same length to each other in a Euclidean Frame

Tags: euclidean-geometry, rigid-transformation

Given two line segments $[P,Q]$ and $[P',Q']$ both in 2D Euclidean frames, with both having the same length, i.e. $d(P,Q) = d(P',Q') \gt 0$ , show that there exists exactly two motions such that $T(P) = P'$ and $T(Q) = Q'$ (where T is the motion).

Now, I know that the $d$ operator only produces positive values. The first motion exists because $d(T(P),T(Q)) = d(P,Q) = d(P',Q')$ would the second simply be $-T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existence: translate by $\vec{PP'}$. Then rotate around $P'$ by $\angle QP'Q'$.
This gives us one movement $T_1$.
Now reflect at line $P'Q'$ afterwards. This gives us a movement $T_2$. (Why is $T_1\ne T_2$?)

Uniquemess: Assume $T_3$ is a third such motion. Then $T_3^{-1}T_1$ and $T_3^{-1}T_2$ and the identity are three motions with $P$ and $Q$ as fixed points. There are only two such motions (why?), hence two of the three are equal. The only possibility os that one of $T_3^{-1}T_1$, $T_3^{-1}T_2$ equald the identity, hence $T_3$ equals one of $T_1,T_2$.

Comment: I think $T_1 \neq T_2$ because a point orthogonal to $\vec{PQ}$ (which would form a frame in 2D) could be mapped to either side of $\vec{P'Q'}$, hence the rotation. I think this also answers why there are only two motions because one Euclidean frame is isometric to another, thus the only option for the orthogonal point is on either side of $\vec{P'Q'}$?